# Date not writing to parquet file as expected

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I'm having an issue with Dates not showing as expected once they have been written to a parquet file from a Pandas df.

Here is a brief description of my work flow:

Step1: Parquet file1 is located in a storage account and can be queried using Synapse serverless SQL. When queried values in the Date column shows as expected i.e. 2022-01-01 (yyyy-MM-dd) No time is included in the source data.

Step2: Parquet file1 is loaded into into a pandas df using pd.read_parquet. Once the parquet file has been loaded into the df the dtype for the Date column is datetime64[ns].

Step3: Some processing of the df is performed that effectively adds some columns to the existing columns in the df, keeping the same indexes. The Date column is not changed.

Step4: Before the df is written to parquet it is confirmed that the Date column is still of dtype datetime64[ns]. and listing the contents df['Date'] gives values such as 2022-01-13.

Step5: The df is written to parquet file2 using df.to_parquet.

Step6: Parquet file2 is queried in synapse serverless SQL and the values in the Date column show as a EPOCH time for example: 1640995200000000

How do I get the Date to be stored in file2 in the same way as it is in file1? I don't need a timestamp but if required to get it to work one could be added i.e. 'T00:00:00'?

Pandas is using pyarrow for the parquet parsing in my current setup.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` does not support dates natively, only timestamps.

For some reason when you read your data from parquet, dates are re-interpreted as timestamps and when you save it back to parquet they remain as timestamp.

You can either change your code so that dates don't get converted to timestamps.

Or you can convert your timestamps back to date before saving it to parquet:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Date": pd.Series(pd.Timestamp(2023,1,1))}
)

def convert_timestamps_to_dates_df(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == "datetime64[ns]":
            df[col] = df[col].dt.date
    return df


convert_timestamps_to_dates_df(df).to_parquet("file.parquet")
```